# cakephp specify Theme for an Element in Controller

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

In cakephp, how do we specify which theme to use for an Element. I am initializing View object in Controller. I need to pass the element content as ajax response.

Controller :

```
$view = new View($this);        
        $view->layout = 'theme2';
        $view->theme = 'newNav';
        foreach($ctps as $ctpName)
        {
             $ctp[] = $view->element($ctpName);
        }
```

At first I thought of accessing it as

```
         $ctp[] = $view->element('../Themed/new/Elements/'.$ctpName);
```

But it obviously does not take care about element's directory. As some of the elements are in app/View/Elements and some are in app/ViewThemed/new/Elements/ directory.

Please suggest.

As per Arilia's suggestion, I am now trying

```
     $this->viewClass = "Theme";
     $this->viewPath = 'Elements';
     $view = new View($this);   
     $view->theme = "new";   
     $view->layout = "theme";

     $ctp = $view->element('userprofile');
     echo json_encode($ctp);
     die;
```

I am making an ajax call to this code. and it returns
"Element Not Found: Elements/userprofile.ctp"

Comment: I think that the element take the theme you set in the contoller. So in your controller you have to write `$this->theme = 'new';`

Comment: `I am initializing View object in Controller` - what is it you're actually doing? That's not normal (e.g. I've never done that). If a theme is specified, [theme files are used automatically if they exist](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/themes.html#themes). Please tag your question with the version of CakePHP you are using.

Comment: Hi Arilia,
As per your suggestions, I went through the View and Controller Api. and, now I am using properties accordingly. I have made the changes and its yet not working. I have edited the question with changes in code.

Comment: @AD7six : requirement was to return html template on ajax call and overwrite the display on Browser. For that i had to initialize View object in controller.

Comment: @AD7six : thank you for pointing it out. I have made the corrections. Please help.

Comment: No you haven't. put your full controller action code in the question, not just a snippet of it. If you get an error message put the whole message and stack trace in the question, not just the one line. What theme files exist? what elements exist? I hope these questions guide you to make it possible not to guess what you're doing or what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

what I was trying to develop was to render the basic page at first so that it can be cached. and then with the ajax call fetch the parts of UI that are session dependent and then replace the respective elements on browser.

To implement this, I tried fetching cakephp elements in controller, json encoding them and echoing them back. The code above though it worked for a normal dynamic page, it did not work for ajax calls. Cakephp somehow misbehaved here.

Now, as a better alternative, I have moved the code to View itself and I am echoing the json encoded from there. and as expected it is working well. Code is as

app/View/Themed/new/Elements/get_ctps.ctp :

```
<?php
foreach($ctps as $ctpName)
{
      $ctp[] = $view->element($ctpName);
}
echo json_encode($ctp);
```

die;
?>

Its not a usual case. However, it might be helpful for someone.